# htaccess problem

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been exploring this issue for the first time and I am struggling big time.

I have a file called home.php and wanted the url localhost/home to point to this.

I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/home /home.php [L]
```

Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home$ /home.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this also but still getting the "Internal Server Error" error. I read below about the infinite loop, I'm not sure why it is entering it?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for all the help. I figured out that I had not enabled mod_rewrite opps(although I was pretty sure I had). The rewrite rule is now working. Thanks everyone!

Comment: How do you redirect a user when they type: example.com/profile/edit/123 I want it to redirect to the following: example.com/profile.php?action=edit&&id=123

Comment: RewriteRule ^/profile/edit/(.*)$ /profile.php?action=edit&id=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing slashes

```
RewriteRule ^home$ home.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi Eineki, Thanks for the response. I tried that but get "Internal Server Error" error message :( Is there something wrong with my set up?

Comment: You have infinite rewrite loop. Add `$` at the end of pattern, e.g. `RewriteRule ^home$ home.php [L]`

Comment: @LazyOne Added, by the way, is not [L] bailing out from the rewriter engine as soon the rule is applied?

Comment: @Eineki See my explanation to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working/6800150#6800150