# RewriteCond with SetEnv

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In my `.htaccess` I set:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

And I want to check if `APPLICATION_ENV` equals `development` then run `app_dev.php`, otherwise `app.php`

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteCond %{ENV:APPLICATION_ENV} development
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

However it does not work - always runs `app.php` script. How should I fix it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since I had to test this myself and could only confirm that what you wrote was correct, I started to look around and found this [post](http://turboflash.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/apache-environment-variables-visibility-with-setenv-setenvif-and-rewriterule-directives/) regarding `SetEnv`, `SetEnvIf` and `RewriteRule` visibility. It looks like `SetEnv` is not visible for `RewriteCond` and if I change your example to use:

```
SetEnvIf APPLICATION_ENV  ^(.*)$ APPLICATION_ENV=development
```

I actually get the rules you have to load `app_dev.php`. You could set the variable using `RewriteRule` as well:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=APPLICATION_ENV:development,NE]
```

However, looks like `SetEnv` can't be used (Tested on Apache 2.2.22).

**EDIT**
As julp pointed out in a comment to this post this is quite clear in Apache document section [Setting Environment Variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html#setting):

```
The SetEnv directive runs late during request processing meaning that directives 
such as SetEnvIf and RewriteCond will not see the variables set with it.
```

Comment: You're right, the explanation is in [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_env.html#setenv): The internal environment variables set by this directive [SetEnv] are set after most early request processing directives are run, such as access control and URI-to-filename mapping. If the environment variable you're setting is meant as input into this early phase of processing such as the RewriteRule directive, you should instead set the environment variable with SetEnvIf.

Comment: I've tested this issue on apache2, no better result as the OP.

Comment: @julp Ahh, thanks I don't understand how I could have missed it when reading about it. Good to have it explained in the official docs.

Comment: @Qben Thank you for answering. I've set `SetEnvIf` in my `VirtualConf` definition, so `.htaccess` file can be pushed to the production, now I'm free of any hacks. Thanks ! :)