# How to access rewrite rule environment variables set as SetEnv?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to access an environment variable inside the rewrite rules which is previously set using SetEnv
e.g.,
SetEnv intl UK

How do I access this "intl" inside the rules later (not in PHP or any other script)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't.

> The SetEnv directive runs late during request processing meaning that
>   directives such as SetEnvIf and RewriteCond will not see the variables
>   set with it.

Please refer to this previous question.
[RewriteCond with SetEnv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362746/rewritecond-with-setenv)