# How can I use SetEnvIf based on matches in the query string?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

The URL I'm using is, let's say, `example.com/subdir/index.php?foo=bar`

index.php contains this: `<?php echo getenv("testenvvar"); ?>`

I'm setting an enviroment variable in .htaccess like so:

`SetEnvIf Request_URI (index) TestEnv=Worked`

This prints "Worked".

If I change it to `SetEnvIf Request_URI (bar) TestEnv=Worked`, it does not.

How can I do this?

Comment: You are trying to access a string from the query arguments, that won't work. The query part simply is _not_ part of the `RequestURI`! This is clearly stated in the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif That documenation actually points out specifically, where you can find an answer to your question :-)

Comment: I'd read that documentation, but it conflicted with my testing.  In any case, it didn't yield me the answer.  Apparently I should use RewriteCond, but I don't see how.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362746/rewritecond-with-setenv which refers to there: https://turboflash.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/apache-environment-variables-visibility-with-setenv-setenvif-and-rewriterule-directives/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match query string you will need `mod_rewrite` rules instead of `mod_setenv`.

Place this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} bar [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TestEnv:Worked]
```

Comment: it would be nice if you explained what is going on.
[NC] means case insensitive,
^ - means don't change the url, just set and environment variable,

Comment: `NC` is for ignore case match. It will match bar, Bar, BAR , baR etc in above example.

Answer (score 9):

Another option would be [SetEnvIfExpr](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvifexpr):

```
SetEnvIfExpr "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /bar/" TestEnv=Worked
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain more detailed how I applied it.

Assume we want to add a X-Robots-Tag header when the following URL is being requested:
https://example.com/?whatever=true

This can be achieved by adding the following rules to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?whatever=true$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=NOINDEXFOLLOW:true]
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SetEnvIfExpr and REDIRECT_NOINDEXFOLLOW works for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIfExpr "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /bar/" NOINDEXFOLLOW
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=REDIRECT_NOINDEXFOLLOW
```