# htaccess env variable and headers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to add an Access-Control-Origin header in `.htaccess` for all URIs ending with `.json`. I cannot use `<FilesMatch>` as my paths are rewritten by mod_rewrite. (Or if I can it doesn't work.)

I found on Stack that it should be possible to do it with an env variable:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.json$" IS_JSON=TRUE
    # ".json$" yields the same result
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_JSON
    # "Header add" yields the same result
</IfModule>
```

But it does never add the header.

I tried using a snipper from [another stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6861746/2188587) to check if the env variable is there using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !echo.php
RewriteRule .* echo.php?uri=%{REQUEST_URI}&json=%{ENV:IS_JSON} [L]
```

And it really was `true`.

When I remove the condition and leave it as:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

the header is added, so the mod is loaded, but I would like to limit it for ".json$" only.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Header` you probably meant to use `RequestHeader` to send custom headers to your code

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.json$ IS_JSON
RequestHeader set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_JSON
```