# Subdomain to Folder using Apache mod_rewrite related Problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain, subdirectory

I want to map all my subdomain to folder.
For example subdomain.domain.com should display content of domain.com/clients/subdmain (Transparently)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.oomail\.org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.oomail\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /var/www/clients/%1/$1
```

I got 500 Internal Server Error. To check whats the problem I appended [R] flag

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /var/www/clients/%1/$1 [R]
```

I got this result in address bar

```
http://q1.oomail.org/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/var/www/clients/q1/always.html
```

Then I created a details.php file which dumps the $_GET variable details. Its content is

```
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
?>
</pre>
```

and modified RewriteRule to (Note: **I am sending $1 and %1 into details.php which shows its content**)

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ details.php?p=%1&d=$1
```

And after opening `http://subdomain.oomail.org/file.html`, I got output as

```
array(2) {
  ["p"]=>
  string(9) "subdomain"
  ["d"]=>
  string(11) "details.php"
}
```

Of which variable **p** is correct (value of %1) which is "subdomain", BUT **d** (value of $1) is details.php which I was expecting to be **file.html** which I opened in URL. Where am I going wrong? or How can I fetch file.html (URI) into variable for mapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clients/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.oomail\.org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.oomail\.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /clients/%1/$1 [L]
```

In your first attempt you had endless **rewrite loop** which Apache had to interrupt (by default no more than 10 iterations). In second attempt you are facing limited rewrite loop (2 iterations, I believe). That's how mod_rewrite works and you should count such possibility in your rules -- especially when you use `.*` as matching pattern .

The very first condition in my rule will prevent rewrite loop from happening (means rule will only work on very first iteration). Unfortunately this means some restrictions: the original URL **CANNOT** start with `/clients/`. For example: this URL will not be redirected: `http://something.example.com/clients/hello-kitten.php`.

**Solution** -- *rename `clients` folder to something more unique:* for example `_clients_folder_` (you would have to change that folder in rewrite rules as well, obviously).

Something to read: [RewriteRule Last [L] flag not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working)