# Weird ModRewrite recursion

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have written this simple `.htaccess` file on my localhost for testing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1a    
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1b
```

Now requesting `http://localhost/test/x`, I get the error `Forbidden` on `/test/xa/xba/xa/xbba/xa/xba/xa/xbbba/xa/xba/xa/xbba/xa/xba/xa/xbbbba/...`

I don't understand why this happens, since I don't use the `[N]` flag, or anything else, that should cause mod_rewrite to recurse. Also, even if it did recurse, I would expect `/test/xabababababababababa...` not that nearly tree looking pattern above.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Also weird: Adding `[L]` to the first line gives an Internal Server Error, while adding it to the second line changes nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is how mod_rewrite works -- after rewriting happens it goes to next iteration (when exactly -- it depends on rewrite flags and other "moments").

If you do not build your rule in a correct manner you will have rewrite loop, which Apache has to forcibly stop at some point.

Useful link to read: [RewriteRule Last [L] flag not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working)