# Redirecting all URL and file requests through .htaccess based on whether file exists or not

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is what I am trying to do:

- When a file is requested from filesystem and it does not exist, rewrite the URL to /index.php?404
- When file is requested and it does exist in filesystem, rewrite the URL to /index.php?file
- In every other case rewrite the URL to /index.php?data

But I am getting 500 errors as a result, does anyone know where the problem might be? I have used RewriteEngine in the past, but it's still a bit confusing to me regarding how to use it for special cases like this.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* ./index.php?404 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* ./index.php?file [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* ./index.php?data [L]
```

Comment: Note that the above system does work if I take the second condition out. This confuses me, since the regular expression itself is the same.

Comment: You have infinite rewrite loop. To solve -- add extra condition to not rewrite already rewritten URLs .. or at least ignore requests to index.php. P.S. How `L` flag works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working

Comment: You're correct, it was a rewrite loop. I'd accept this as an answer if you make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have infinite rewrite loop. To solve -- add extra condition to not rewrite already rewritten URLs .. or at least ignore requests to `index.php`.

One of the possible approaches:

```
# do not touch any requests to index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

**P.S.**
How L flag works: [RewriteRule Last [L] flag not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working)