# How can I use an exception to a RewriteRule redirect?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ index.php?post=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

I expect it to rewrite (for example) `mysite.com/x` to `mysite.com/index.php?page=x`, with the exception of `mysite.com/post/x` rewritten to `mysite.com/index.php?post=x`, however it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just adding `[L]` flag will not be enough, as rewriting goes in cycles until no more rewrites occurs.**

[RewriteRule Last [L] flag not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working)

---

There are quite a few approaches -- here is one of them (possibly the best one considering your example rules).

```
# do not do anything for index.php (already rewritten URLs)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# my rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ index.php?post=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

add the `L` directive, e.g. `RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ index.php?post=$1 [L,NC]`

`L` meaning last, i.e. if the rewrite rule is matched it will stop processing the next rules ...

Comment: You should do this for both rules.