# Two nearly identical RewriteRules, one works, one doesn't?

Tags: .htaccess

I want everything to be redirected to index.php, so I thought this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

..but it doesn't. This very similar RewriteRule does work though:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule matches/(.*) /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

I later found out that to make the first one work you need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Can someone please explain why the last RewriteCond is needed in the former example but not the latter?

Comment: The answer would depend on everything *else* on the server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because first rule will rewrite already rewritten URL.

[RewriteRule Last [L] flag not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working)

**For example:**

- Original request: `/hello/pink-kitten`
- 1st (initial) rewrite: `/index.php?url=hello/pink-kitten`
- 2nd cycle: rewritten to `/index.php?url=index.php`
- 3rd cycle: rewritten to `/index.php?url=index.php`
- No more cycles, as 3rd cycle produced the same result as 2nd

**Why rule works if added that condition?** Because the condition **clearly** says -- only do rewrite if requested URL is not file. Therefore, on 2nd cycle URL will not be rewritten again as `/index.php` is a file, therefore no more cycles.

**Why 2nd rule works just like that?** Because it already has condition built in -- URL should contain `matches/` in it, and rewritten URL `/index.php?url=` as you can see has no `matches/` part in it.

Comment: One question then, which one would be correct to serve everything to index.php:  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1  

or  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php  
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1

Comment: First one -- it will process requests to NOT existing files only, so css/js/images/etc will be served by web server as usual. 2nd one (BTW, it will not work, as condition is a bit wrong) will rewrite EVERYTHING to the index.php, even existing static files.