# .htaccess stop internal redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

First of all, this is my directory structure

```
/localhost/p/
  .htaccess
/localhost/p/inc/
  style.css
```

I have this snippet on `/localhost/p/.htaccess`

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /p/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteCond %1/inc/%2 -f
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ inc/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

It won't allow me to access a file at `localhost/p/style.css` but it will let me access index.php

here is the log

```
[perdir D:/p/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/p/style.css -> style.css
[perdir D:/p/] applying pattern '([^/]+)$' to uri 'style.css'
[perdir D:/p/] RewriteCond: input='D:/p/style.css' pattern='^(.+)/([^/]+)$' => matched
[perdir D:/p/] RewriteCond: input='D:/p/inc/style.css' pattern='-f' => matched
[perdir D:/p/] rewrite 'style.css' -> 'inc/style.css'
[perdir D:/p/] add per-dir prefix: inc/style.css -> D:/p/inc/style.css

// I don't know how to stop the .htaccess here, and just get the file
// instead go with [INTERNAL REDIRECT]

[perdir D:/p/] trying to replace prefix D:/p/ with /p/
strip matching prefix: D:/p/inc/style.css -> inc/style.css
add subst prefix: inc/style.css -> /p/inc/style.css
[perdir D:/p/] internal redirect with /p/inc/style.css [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[perdir D:/p/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/p/inc/style.css -> inc/style.css
[perdir D:/p/] applying pattern '([^/]+)$' to uri 'inc/style.css'
[perdir D:/p/] RewriteCond: input='D:/p/inc/style.css' pattern='^(.+)/([^/]+)$' => matched
[perdir D:/p/] RewriteCond: input='D:/p/inc/inc/style.css' pattern='-f' => not-matched

// Of course it will never match, it should be D:/p/inc/style.css

...
...
...
```

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot stop it -- that's just how it works (in loops) -- read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this RewriteCond to allow no more than 1 internal redirection:

```
## prevent looping from internal redirects
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
```

Comment: btw, where should I put that line? wrong order will return unexpected result right? thanks

Comment: Put it before this line: `RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ inc/$1 [L]`