# Rewritemap to url with spaces

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to:

- give access to file in folder if query string value exist in map file
- disable access if query string value is empty or no query string at all

With the following it works except for files with spaces: london bridge footage.mp4

/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

... truncated ssl certificate ...

RewriteEngine On

# Rewritemap:
RewriteMap filehash txt:file_hash.txt

# Query string equal to key=digits lookup in map
# redirect to /404 on fail else redirect to match in map
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(key=)([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^/test/video/(.*)$ ${filehash:%2|/404}? [PT,NE,L]

# Query string empty: key=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^key=+$
RewriteRule ^/test/video/(.*)$ - [R=404,L]

# No query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/test/video/(.*)$ - [R=404,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

file_hash.txt

```
1001 /test/video/london_bridge_footage.mp4
1002 /test/video/london bridge footage.mp4
1003 /test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4
1004 /test/video/london\ bridge\ footage.mp4
```

EDIT:

added more information about my configuration, i have Codeigniter 4 running in up folder /test/ who use rewrite rules

/etc/httpd/httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/test">
   LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

/var/www/test/.htaccess

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    RewriteBase /test

    # Rewrite CSS / JS "theme.1603357209.css -> theme.css"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.\d+(\.(?:js|css))$ $1$2

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>

# Add cache control header one year for CSS and JS files
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

EDIT 2:

rewritelog for a working file:

```
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:44.436405 2022] [core:notice] [pid 2002:tid 140071990364096] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:49.518993 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26321:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42860] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40139e0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/video/london_bridge_footage.mp4 -> video/london_bridge_footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:49.519018 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26321:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42860] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40139e0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^(.+)\\.\\d+(\\.(?:js|css))$' to uri 'video/london_bridge_footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:49.519025 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26321:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42860] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40139e0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/video/london_bridge_footage.mp4 -> video/london_bridge_footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:49.519045 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26321:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42860] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40139e0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'video/london_bridge_footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:49.519060 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26321:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42860] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40139e0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/video/london_bridge_footage.mp4 -> video/london_bridge_footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:49.520125 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26321:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42860] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40139e0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'video/london_bridge_footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:49.520143 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26321:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42860] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40139e0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/video/london_bridge_footage.mp4 -> video/london_bridge_footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:49.520146 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26321:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42860] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40139e0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^([\\s\\S]*)$' to uri 'video/london_bridge_footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:49.520161 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26321:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42860] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40139e0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/video/london_bridge_footage.mp4 -> video/london_bridge_footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:49.520165 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26321:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42860] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40139e0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'video/london_bridge_footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:28:49.520170 2022] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 26321:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42860] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40139e0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] pass through /var/www/test/video/london_bridge_footage.mp4
```

A file that fail

```
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837894 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4 -> video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837918 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^(.+)\\.\\d+(\\.(?:js|css))$' to uri 'video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837924 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4 -> video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837927 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837942 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4 -> video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837945 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837948 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4 -> video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837951 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^([\\s\\S]*)$' to uri 'video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837956 2022] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] rewrite 'video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4' -> 'index.php/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837966 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4 -> /var/www/test/index.php/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837970 2022] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/test/ with /test
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.837973 2022] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f40128a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] internal redirect with /test/index.php/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838010 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] add path info postfix: /var/www/test/index.php -> /var/www/test/index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838015 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4 -> index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838018 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^(.+)\\.\\d+(\\.(?:js|css))$' to uri 'index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838022 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] add path info postfix: /var/www/test/index.php -> /var/www/test/index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838025 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4 -> index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838027 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838046 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] add path info postfix: /var/www/test/index.php -> /var/www/test/index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838049 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4 -> index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838054 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838057 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] add path info postfix: /var/www/test/index.php -> /var/www/test/index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838062 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4 -> index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838065 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^([\\s\\S]*)$' to uri 'index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838070 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] add path info postfix: /var/www/test/index.php -> /var/www/test/index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838074 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4 -> index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838076 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'index.php/video/london bridge footage.mp4'
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:19.838081 2022] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 26391:tid 140071799514688] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400cc00/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] pass through /var/www/test/index.php
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061135 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.1658174761.js -> assets/dist/js/theme.1658174761.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061153 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^(.+)\\.\\d+(\\.(?:js|css))$' to uri 'assets/dist/js/theme.1658174761.js', referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061170 2022] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] rewrite 'assets/dist/js/theme.1658174761.js' -> 'assets/dist/js/theme.js', referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061174 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] add per-dir prefix: assets/dist/js/theme.js -> /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061177 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.js -> assets/dist/js/theme.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061180 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'assets/dist/js/theme.js', referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061197 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.js -> assets/dist/js/theme.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061201 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'assets/dist/js/theme.js', referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061205 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.js -> assets/dist/js/theme.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061208 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^([\\s\\S]*)$' to uri 'assets/dist/js/theme.js', referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061213 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.js -> assets/dist/js/theme.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061217 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'assets/dist/js/theme.js', referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061225 2022] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/test/ with /test, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061228 2022] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f4017a10/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/] internal redirect with /test/assets/dist/js/theme.js [INTERNAL REDIRECT], referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061246 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400b7d0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.js -> assets/dist/js/theme.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061251 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400b7d0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^(.+)\\.\\d+(\\.(?:js|css))$' to uri 'assets/dist/js/theme.js', referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061255 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400b7d0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.js -> assets/dist/js/theme.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061258 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400b7d0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'assets/dist/js/theme.js', referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061271 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400b7d0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.js -> assets/dist/js/theme.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061275 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400b7d0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'assets/dist/js/theme.js', referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061278 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400b7d0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.js -> assets/dist/js/theme.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061281 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400b7d0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '^([\\s\\S]*)$' to uri 'assets/dist/js/theme.js', referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061289 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400b7d0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.js -> assets/dist/js/theme.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061293 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400b7d0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'assets/dist/js/theme.js', referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
[Mon Jul 18 22:32:20.061299 2022] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 26391:tid 140071791121984] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client 192.168.1.254:42862] 192.168.1.254 - - [my-domain.org/sid#5561d7dc23b8][rid#7f64f400b7d0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/test/] pass through /var/www/test/assets/dist/js/theme.js, referer: https://my-domain.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key=1003
```

Maybe related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811081/htaccess-stop-internal-redirect) ?

EDIT 3

Following Anubhava advices i copied his .htaccess but it did not work, files was reachable with or without query string, i have edited as follow this two lines:

```
# with + instead of * ?key= return the file
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=(\d*) [NC]
# Without ? internal server error
RewriteRule ^video/ ${filehash:%1}? [L,NC]
```

What is working:

- map works fine with all type of files, with or without spaces
  if a query string ?key=digits is provided.
- if query string is ?key= or ?key=0000 no file is returned
- if not matching map the front controller return a 404

What is not working:

- the file is downloadable if i use any uri between file extension and query string equal sign:
  `https://my-site.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key`

I have tested plenty of variations with no luck the last past few hours.

Httpd is 2.4.54

Help appreciated

EDIT 4:

it is now working, thank you so much to Anubhava for his help, the solution was inside another post that was solved by Anubhava

```
# Query string equal to key=digits lookup in map 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=(\d*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^video/ ${filehash:%1}? [L,NC,NE]

# for video URL if key=<digits> is not present then 404
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)key=(\d+) [NC]
# prevent looping from internal redirects
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^video/ /404/ [L,NC]
```

EDIT 5

In the same time Anubhava provided another working solution see accepted answer.

Comment: I have a framework running in `/test/` folder with rewriterules could it be source of the problem ?

Comment: @anubhava added more informations

Comment: @anubhava thanks you for your help, problem must come from somehting in my setup, will continue to investigate

Comment: @anubhava i updated my initial post with rewritelog of both successfull and unsuccesfull file, i found a post with a maybe similar issue where you responded but this clearly is over my knowledge

Comment: @anubhava Not shure to fully undestand your question, the first rule in my post is in `/etc/http/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` in my `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Comment: @anubhava no, missing query string return 404

Comment: ok comment out both `R=404` rules and test if that load the correct file?

Comment: @anubhava yes it load

Comment: @anubhava yes you can see my EDIT 3 in original post

Comment: file is downloadable if i use any uri between file extension and query string equal sign: `https://my-site.org/test/video/london%20bridge%20footage.mp4?key`

Comment: @anubhava it does not work, i'm unable to download at all with the new rule. Is it possible that the reason is that `RewriteRule ^films/ ${filehash:%1}? [L,NC]` add a `?` and the query string is removed, then the new rule don't find query string and the request is blocked ?

Comment: Yes that's the issue. Please try my updated answer now. Note that I have changed order of rules and added one more condition

Comment: @anubhava I found a solution see my EDIT 4. I test your new update and give you a feedback

Comment: Indeed you suggestion is on similar lines as in my latest update so it should all be working fine now. I guess biggest catch was moving rules in one place so that `mp4` files with spaces started loading.

Comment: @anubhava Your latest update work perfectly, thank you so much for your help. Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you remove every rule from vhost except `RewriteMap` and keep all the rules in one place i.e. `test/.htaccess` as it already exists in your file system.

**/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:**

```bash
<VirtualHost *:443>

... truncated ssl certificate ...

RewriteEngine On
# Rewritemap:
RewriteMap filehash txt:file_hash.txt
</VirtualHost>
```

**/test/.htaccess:**

```bash
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
# change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
RewriteBase /test/

# Rewrite CSS / JS "theme.1603357209.css -> theme.css"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.\d+(\.(?:js|css))$ $1$2 [L,NC]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]


# for video URL if key=<digits> is not present then 404
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)key=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^video/ /404/ [L,NC]

# Query string equal to key=digits lookup in map
# redirect to /404 on fail else redirect to match in map
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^video/ ${filehash:%1|/404/}? [L,NC]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to the front controller, index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Ensure Authorization header is passed along
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Add cache control header one year for CSS and JS files
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Also you should not use `R=404` rules because `index.php` is acting as front controller that handled all non-files, non-directory requests anyway.

Comment: Make sure to test if from a new browser or command line curl to avoid old cache.