# Htaccess subdomain + multilingual website

Tags: .htaccess, multilingual

I have a problem with subdomains I used to translate my website. With the 4 first lines of code, I've no problem, the **sub** var is passed fine (*http://en.mywebsite.com/* gives *http://mywebsite.com?sub=en*). The 5th line is used to manage ads, once I click on the link like *http://en.mywebsite.com/blue-chair-Vha6J.html* the page isn't loaded and I stay on the home page. It should gives me something like *http://mywebsite.com?sub=en&menu=ad&ad=Vha6J*. Instead of this, it gives me *http://mywebsite.com?sub=en*.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) ?sub=%1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.html$ ?sub=%1&menu=ad&ad=$2 [L]
```

**[EDIT 1]**

Ok, here is a bigger htaccess extract, included the modifications I made with the first answer, and I still have problems :

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&menu=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ?sub=%1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^cart$ ?sub=%1&menu=cart [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ ?sub=%1&menu=login [L]

########### AD
RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.html$ ?sub=%1&menu=ad&ad=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.html\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ ?sub=%1&menu=ad&ad=$2&secret=$3 [L]

########### ADS
RewriteRule ^all\/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ ?sub=%1&menu=ads&section_name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^all\/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ ?sub=%1&menu=ads&section_name=$1&category_name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^all\/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ ?sub=%1&menu=ads&section_name=$1&category_name=$2&subCategory_name=$3 [L]

########### SHOPS
RewriteRule ^shops$ ?sub=%1&menu=shops [L]

########### SHOP
RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]+)$ ?sub=%1&menu=shop&shop=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]+)\/([-a-z0-9]+)$ ?sub=%1&menu=shop&shop=$1&category_name=$2 [L]
```

When I'm on the home page *https://en.mywebsite.com/*, the **sub** var "en" is passed fine. If I go on *https://en.mywebsite.com/login* for instance, the page is loaded, but the **sub** var "en" isn't passed.

Any idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the url is Rewritten twice , the first time `/sample-vg.html` is rewritten correctly to `?sub=en&menu=ad&ad=fg`, then in the second run the new url is been rewritten again to `?sub=en` (L flag just stop the current run, not the entire process, [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800150/1117720))

there is also a problem with the second RewriteRule(undefined %1),

the following code should work as expected:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&ad=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) ?sub=%1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.html$ ?sub=%1&menu=ad&ad=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you Amine, it works fine. But, now my problem is I have many different rules like the one `RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.html$ ?sub=%1&menu=ad&ad=$2 [L]` So, do I have to add on the top, for each rule, something like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&ad=.*` where "ad" changes? Is there a solution to manage all **%{QUERY_STRING}** in one line ?

Comment: I've updated my first post, including the modifications, if you want to look at it.