# How can I rewrite everything but my first rule in htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I need to rewrite all URLs in a specific format to their matching querystring'd URL and everything else should go to index.php?valid=false

I have:

```
RewriteRule (^[^\s]{4})/([0-9]{4})/(winter|fall|summer)/([0-9]{4})/?$ index.php?valid=true&subject=$1&course=$2&semester=$3&year=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*)/?$ index.php?valid=false [NC,L]
```

The first rule is working fine: 4 letters, 4 numbers, fall or winter or summer, 4 numbers. And it seems like the second rule is working because everything is currently redirecting to the `?valid=false` page. However, even URLs that are accepted by the first rule (when the 2nd one is commented out) pass through to the second one, even though they should be stopped by the `[L]` flag?

Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working

Comment: @sgroves thanks - that's an informative link - the answer below is working for me, but the rewritecond (or the helpful flowcharts) in that link might solve another issue I am having with a different rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteRule (^[^\s]{4})/([0-9]{4})/(winter|fall|summer)/([0-9]{4})/?$ index.php?valid=true&subject=$1&course=$2&semester=$3&year=$4 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?valid=false [NC,L]
```

i.e. execute 2nd rule only when URI is not already `index.php`

Comment: Awesome, it works. However, it introduces another issue I didn't think of. It is also rewriting my file include links such as CSS/Images/JS so they aren't returning the actual files needed to display the page properly. I seemed to have fixed that by including the following RewriteCond's before the 2nd rule - is this the correct way to do it without introducing other issues down the line? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: Yes indeed those 2 checks are needed to avoid rewriting for a file or directory. I have edited it accordingly.