# .htaccess: Serve static files, route everything else to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webfaction

I want to use an `.htaccess` file to check if the requested path is a file in the `public/` directory. If yes, serve it, else forward request to `/index.php`. I can't seem to get this to work.

Here's what I've got:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

e.g. `http://example.com/css/style.css` should have apache serve `/public/css/style.css` because it's a file that exists, but `http://example.com/css/style.bad` should be sent to `/index.php`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently [`[L]` does not work as I expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800150/65387). With that in mind, and a lot of trial and error, I managed to find something that works:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 6):

This code should be working as expected on your side

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/public/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. I just noticed though that `style.css` is available at *both* `/css/style.css` *and* `/public/css/style.css` though. Technically the latter should route to `index.php` too since `/public/public/css.style.css` is not a file. This also means `/public/xxx` will throw an apache 404 instead of the custom one I've configured in my `index.php` file. No way to fix that, is there?