# htacess, .{0,10} works, .+ doesn't for redirects, giving error 500

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to serve any request using files from within a subdirectory. Example:

Browser requests localhost/style.css,

Server responds (without redirecting the browser!) from localhost/static/style.css

This works flawlessly using the following .htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.{0,10})$ static/$1
```

But when I do

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ static/$1
```

It fails with "Internal Server Error".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`/var/log/apache2/error.log` said something like

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

I guess it was redirecting from `style.css` to `static/style.css`, then to `static/static/style.css`, and so on. The solution was to use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ static/$1
```

the RewriteCond line prevents the next RewriteRule to redirect when the url starts with static/

This here is also quite helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800150/4417769

htacess iterates over the rules again after the redirect, so it gets applied recursively and [L] cannot stop it.

---

another solution would be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ static/$1
```

which only redirects if the url after the redirect matches a file that exists