# RewriteRule Last [L] flag not considered?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have created a php framework that works well on an IIS server and the RewriteRules work perfectly well with web.config.

But the same rules don't work on an apache server with .htaccess and I don't understand why... here they are:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule picture/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z\-0-9/]+).(jpg|png|gif)    app/Src/$1Bundle/public/img/$2.$3 [L]
RewriteRule picture/([a-zA-Z\-0-9/]+).(jpg|png|gif)    public/$1.$2 [L]
RewriteRule scripts/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(js|css|typo)/([a-zA-Z\-0-9=\./]+).(js|css) app/Src/$1Bundle/public/$2/$3.$4 [L]
RewriteRule scripts/(js|css|typo)/([a-zA-Z\-0-9=\./]+).(js|css) public/$1/$2.$3 [L]
RewriteRule scripts/(fonts)/([a-zA-Z\-0-9=\./]+).(eot|svg|ttf|woff)   public/$1/$2.$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have tried this solution (and many others)([RewriteRule Last [L] flag not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working)), but it hasn't worked.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} != 200
```

I have run out of ideas...

Comment: What URLs are not working and what is the error?

Comment: The usual issue with the `L` flag is that people do not understand that it only terminates _this_ run of the rewriting process. The process is however immediately started again if the URL has been rewritten. If you want to _finally_ terminate the rewriting process use the `END` flag instead.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

Your last rule (that rewrites *everything*) runs unconditionally, so this is going to result in a rewrite loop (500 error response).

At the very least you need to prevent requests for `index.php` being further rewritten. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But you presumably also want your static resources to remain directly accessible as well?  So, excluding requests that map to physical files and directories is a common requirement. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

> ```
> RewriteRule picture/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z\-0-9/]+).(jpg|png|gif)    app/Src/$1Bundle/public/img/$2.$3 [L]
> ```

You have also omitted any start-of-string anchors (`^`) and end-of-string anchors (`$`) from your `RewriteRule` *patterns*. This could potentially result in matching too much - even matching the rewritten URL - another loop. You need to be more specific in your pattern matching.