# rewrite rule dont gives GET-Parameter

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA]
```

This rule redirect all requests to my index.php and works like a charm. Now I would like to **ADD** another rule that redirect all requests for the directory /admin/ to admin.php in root. (A request for [www.mysite.de/admin/login](http://www.mysite.de/admin/login) should end in [www.mysite.de/admin.php?a=login&b=](http://www.mysite.de/admin.php?a=login&b=)) The second parameter b should be optional.
How to reach this? Thx for any hint in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can test htaccess rules online (ex. here: [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/))

This code works with:
[www.mysite.de/admin/login](http://www.mysite.de/admin/login)
and
[www.mysite.de/admin/login/123](http://www.mysite.de/admin/login/123)

**edited**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^admin/?([^/]*)/?(.*)$ admin.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?(.*)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

#removed
#RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?/?$ admin.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA]
```

Notice that you need the `L flag` there. ([RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html))

Also useful to see [How L flags work - StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797998/rewriterule-last-l-flag-not-working) and [Everything about mod rewrite - serverfault.com thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Comment: thx verjas. But for me all request are sent to index.php. admin.php is not touched.

Comment: On  htaccess.madewithlove.be it works. On my server not. Anny suggestion?

Comment: The L seems to be ignored

Comment: I tried the edited version. It moves now to admin.php but the ?a=$1&b=$2 are not given. (The php var_dump($_GET) is always empty)

Comment: hm. It works for me, tested it on my server. Maybe we can move this to chat for a few minutes: [so php chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php)

Comment: Sorry but I saw your offer to chat just now. I still be interested.